# Why do equality and inequality comparison against a completely nan categorical series always return False?

Tags: python, pandas

I have discovered this to be the root of a confusing issue for me. Pandas 1.05

```
>>> left = pd.Series(pd.Categorical([numpy.nan, numpy.nan, numpy.nan, numpy.nan], categories=["1"], ordered=False))
>>> right = pd.Series(pd.Categorical(["1", "1", "1", numpy.nan], categories=["1"], ordered=False))

>>> left == right 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool

>>> left != right
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the basic properties of `NaN`, as defined in the ISO standard.

A `NaN` value fails (`returns False`) *any* comparison operation.

```
numpy.nan == numpy.nan
```

is `False`.  Again, this is *required* by the standard.  The concept is that if something is **not a number**, then you can't compare it to anything that *is* a number.  This is *usually* a TypeError, but `NaN` was developed specifically for the need to have a non-number that is, nonetheless, partially compatible with the rest of a numerical data set.  The `Inf` family were also defined in this standard.

Before some of these nifty packages existed, this is how I quickly checked for `NaN` in some simulation code:  `if not(x == x) ...`